# Replace not working with a date convert

Tags: sql, sybase

I have the following query:

```
select distinct 
min(Id),  
Name,
Age,
replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),birthday,113),' ','-') as "Birthday"
from #temp_table
group by name, age
```

Returns a vague error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword replace" If I remove the replace portion it works but returns a date format I don't want. I need the date to be converted in dd-mmm-yy format. The input is mm/dd/yyyy. Doing this in Sybase if that matters.

Comment: Does the query work if you remove the `replace()` and just use `convert()`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes it does.

Comment: What is the version of your sybase?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASE and not IQ, the following ugly beast should work:

> ... 
>   str_replace(str_replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),birthday,106),substring(birthday,7,5),'-' + substring(birthday,10,2)),' ','-')
>   ...

Unfortunately, by Sybase standards that's a pretty unusual date format you're looking for.